# Transform JSON file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a JSON file using XSLT, and so far have come up with the following code, which does not display the expected output, which at this point is the same JSON as the one in the `json` parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:param as="xs:string" name="json">[
   {
      "logic":"ADD",
      "product":{
         "productLength":5,
         "productUnits":"Kg"
      },
      "numberOfUnits":1
   },
   {
      "logic":"ADD",
      "product":{
         "productLength":5,
         "productUnits":"Kg"
      },
      "numberOfUnits":2
   }
]
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
        <xsl:variable as="element(array)" name="transformed-xml">
            <array>
                <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/*/*">
                    <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                        <string key="logic">
                            <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='logic']"/>
                        </string>
                        <map key="product">
                            <string key="productLength">
                                <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='stayLength/stayLength']"/>
                            </string>
                            <string key="productUnits">
                                <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='stayLength/stayLengthUnits']"/>
                            </string>
                        </map>
                        <string key="numberOfUnits">
                            <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='numberOfUnits']"/>
                        </string>
                    </map>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </array>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? This is just a sample of my file, and I am following this approach as I need to re-construct the original JSON file.

I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion in case I need to follow a different approach which you may think is better in this case. The decision to transform JSON using XSLT was not mine, I just need to work with it now.

Comment: Please add a minimal but complete sample, if we don't see any in-scope namespace we can't judge in which namespace `<array>` is, for instance. Also do you get any error? If so, which one?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you, I updated the question with a full example. I don't get any errors, I just am getting a JSON message that has the same structure as the one in the json parameter, but holds no values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths and keys you use are partly wrong as you have not selected the nested map and as you have not selected the number values that are in the original JSON:

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
    <xsl:variable as="element(array)" name="transformed-xml">
        <array>
            <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/*/*">
                <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                    <string key="logic">
                        <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='logic']"/>
                    </string>
                    <map key="product">
                        <number key="productLength">
                            <xsl:value-of select="map/number[@key='productLength']"/>
                        </number>
                        <string key="productUnits">
                            <xsl:value-of select="map/string[@key='productUnits']"/>
                        </string>
                    </map>
                    <number key="numberOfUnits">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number[@key='numberOfUnits']"/>
                    </number>
                </map>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </array>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nh

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, this makes total sense! iF I try to select the ````productLength```` as a ````string```` instead of a ````number````, I then don't see any value in the JSON output. Is there anything I can do to read it as a string?

Comment: What I mean is that the ````productLength```` can come as a string but also as a number, is there a way I can go around this?

Comment: @site - You could construct the element dynamically and select `map/*[@key='productLength']`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nh/2

Comment: @Site, do you want to transform a number into a number and a string into a string or do you want to change the result to contain always a number? In general transformation is best done by adding templates to the identity transformation i.e. in XSLT 3 start with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, that way you get a copy as long as you don't add templates but can selectively match and override the behaviour for the changes you want to make.

Comment: That would be https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nh/3. If you wanted to e.g. change the productLength to be a always a string in the output you would just write a template for that https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nh/4.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you for your help, I appreciate it. This will probably be a stupid question, but If I'd want to override the ````logic```` value, would I be using ````<xsl:template match="map[@key = 'logic']">````?

Comment: I think you need to make yourself familiar with the XML representation of JSON that the `json-to-xml` function creates and that you then transform with XSLT, you can do that both by reading the relevant sections in the XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 specs and of course by experimenting; for instance solely the identity transformation (with output `method="xml"`) on your sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nh/5 shows `<string key="logic">ADD</string>` so to match that you need to match a string `<xsl:template match="string[@key = 'logic']">`, not a map.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have one last question, I know I am abusing with your help, would very much appreciate if you could help with this one too. I would like to check if a specific element ````weight```` exists, and if not add it after ````logic```` with a dummy value.

Comment: @Site, you are basically asking question on various XML to XML transformation task that one hand are covered in any tutorial on XSLT and certainly also in lots of existing posts on this site. So take some time to read up on XSLT and if necessary, ask a new question on that specific transformation step with details of what of input and output, the XSLT you tried and how it failed.